# Использование GRANT в SQL Server

Tags: sql

```
grant select on table1 to Role
```

предоставление прав на просмотр одной таблицы работает, а как указать все таблицы БД?

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксис такого не позволяет. По-моему, будет проще использовать роль db_datareader